# Allowing users to create columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, create-fields

I'm using Sharepoint 2016. I want to allow end users to create new columns within a document library.  I have Full Control rights, and with this I see a 'create column' option, which lets me create new columns of various types. However end users don't see these options. 
What is the minimum level of permission that I must give users, to allow them the same right? I have already given them Edit and Design.

Comment: Edit permission level is more than enough to create a column in SharePoint list. Could you please check again in that list.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the various permission level in SharePoint, please go to the link and replace with your site URL:

```
https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSiteTestByPnP/_layouts/15/role.aspx
```

Please have look at the below each permission level description:

[image: Permission Level In SharePoint]

So if we look at each description, a user with **"Edit"** permission should be able to create column.

Answer (score 0):

Edit permission is enough for users to create columns. Check the [List permission settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) to see if you have set unique permission on the list. Do a permission check with your end users. Make sure they have edit permission on your list.

And test with other brand new custom lists to see if all your users are able to create columns.

Reference:
[Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels)